# Where is the documentation for FlutterFire FirebaseException codes?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm trying to handle Firebase errors in Flutter using FlutterFire. Various functions throw [FirebaseException](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_core/firebase_core_platform_interface/lib/src/firebase_exception.dart), for example if calling an HttpsCallable when there is no internet connection. I need to figure out what to do depending on the error - for example, if there is no internet connection, show a message, else if it's an unknown error log an exception.

The exception has a code to achieve this:

```
  /// The optional code to accommodate the message.
  ///
  /// Allows users to identify the exception from a short code-name, for example
  /// "no-app" is used when a user attempts to read a [FirebaseApp] which does
  /// not exist.
  final String code;
```

But I can't find anywhere where these codes are documented, which kind of makes them useless. I've searched for ages. Am I missing something? Does anyone have a link? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Auth error code [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.Auth) in [code](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/6bd6cd84a624a533857105e30f85650c5c68a2f7/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth_platform_interface/lib/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_firebase_auth.dart)

Core dart [code](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/dca1a35a3bba2c1aabe1659364481a6b80c77a28/packages/firebase_core/firebase_core_platform_interface/lib/src/firebase_core_exceptions.dart)

For user in [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User) in [code](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/6bd6cd84a624a533857105e30f85650c5c68a2f7/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth_platform_interface/lib/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_user.dart)

and so on... Could not find one place where everything is added...